# UINavigation Controller subview Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my application my first Page is a `UITableviewController`. Then I add a `subView` in `UIViewcontroller`  like:

```
viewcontrollername * prod=[[viewcontrollername alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:prod.view];
```

It's fine, but My problem is in `UINavigation` controller not working in `viewcontroller` page(doesn't Navigate to another Page). I have implemented it in click event:

```
prod *login=[[prod alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navCtrl= [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navCtrl pushViewController:login animated:YES];
[login release];
```

And

```
  prod *login=[[prod alloc]init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:YES];
 [login release];
```

But it doesn't Navigate to another Page.

Comment: @marzapower UINavigation controller not working in subview

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting errors? Exceptions? Are you not able to see anything? What?

Comment: @marzapower It doesn't navigate to another page.I didn't get any error

Comment: You should update the question to make it more understandable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code when you init the navigation controller :

```
UINavigationController *navigationCtrlSlideShowSetting = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourviewcontroller];
```

Thanks

Comment: Add the custom back button and event in viewwillappear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `navCtrl` hasn't been added to the view hierarchy. Either you add it as a subview to the `window` or make it the `rootViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first view controller should be the root view controller of the navigation controller.

`initWithRootViewController`

Alternatively you can add the newly created navigation controller to your viewcontroller.

```
[self.view addSubview:navCtrl.view];
```

Once this is done you can push view controllers to the navigation controller.

EDIT:
You need to have a back button in case you do not have a way to come back to main screen. The better option is to use navigation controller for the main screen and go on pushing views onto the stack.

Comment: This is because the login screen becomes the first view of your nav controll and ther are no more views in it. You can create custom back button in view did load method in that case. Its a different approach. I will try to edit my post to fit this.